# calculation of the area of a rectangle

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I struggle organising my code, and I would like to share my "problem" with you by using a simple example: the calculation of the area of a rectangle. I put the code for example, but reading the first intro on each class section explains the situation easily.

### Entity Rectangle:

**The entity Rectangle contains two inportant properties `$length` and `$width`.**

```
// src/Acme/CalculationBundle/Entity/Rectangle.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CalculationBundle\Repository\RectangleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="rectangle")
 */
class Rectangle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $length;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $width;
```

### FORM

Of course, the user can set length and width via a form

### CONTROLLER

**CreateRectangleAction:**  renders the form on GET request and work on the data on a POST request.

**ViewRectangleAction:** shows the rectangle.

### RECTANGLE MANAGER

Now, to make sure the controller doesn't do too much stuff, I use a RectangleManager to realise common operation on Rectangle objects and use it as a service (injecting the appropriate elements).

```
// src/Acme/CalculationBundle/Entity/RectangleManager.php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Acme\EmployerBundle\Entity\Manager;

class rectangleManager
{
    /**
     * Doctrine entity manager
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $class;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $class)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->repository = $em->getRepository($class);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return Rectangle
     */
    public function find($id)
    {
        $rectangle =  $this->repository->find($id);
    }
```

### THE PROBLEM: WHAT IF?

**What if I need to do some calculations on the rectangle?** For example, if I need to add an area property so that I can render the area directly in the template without doing the calculation (length*width) in the template?

Not knowing how to do this properly, I went for this pretty bad solution:

I created a RectangleDisplay class (where I inject the rectangle entity) and display that entity instead of the Rectangle entity when calling ViewRectangleAction in the controller.

```
// src/Acme/CalculationBundle/Entity/
class RectangleDisplay
{
    /**
     * @var Rectangle $rectangle
     */
    protected $rectangle;

    /**
     * @var Integer 
     */
    protected $area;

    /**
     * @param Rectangle $rectangle
     */
    public function __construct(rectangle $rectangle){

        $this->rectangle = $rectangle;
        //calculate are
        $area = this->calculateArea($this->rectangle->getLength(),$this->rectangle->getWidth());
        $this->area = $area;

    }

    /**
     * @return Integer $area
     */
    public function calculateArea($length,$width)
    {
         return $length * $width;
    }
```

Now the property area is directly accessible in the template. In the case of a rectangle, that is fine, but in the case of a more complex element (cone, ...), I might want to use a service that is crazy at doing calculation. I am not gonna inject the container in my RectangleDisplayEntity, am I?

Comment: Why don't you extend your Rectangle Model with methods you need? Just add there property, getters and setters - and you'll be able to get them wherever the model is called.

Comment: Sure, that's much better! But how can I call the service container on this entity to use calculation methods that are specialised in this task. I don't know if it's a good Idea to use the service container in an entity, is it?

Comment: You don't need to have the service for calculations. Just move the calculation logic to getter method in the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs in your entity.

```
class Rectangle
{
    // ...

    public function getArea()
    {
        return $this->length * $this->width;
    }
}
```

The area of a rectangle is a *property* of a rectangle.  It's not some crazy calculation that should be delegated to another service, and it's especially not something display-related (though you may think that based on it being displayed in your application).

Now, if you were calculating something a lot more complex, it's probably worth moving to a service / another class.  (Services = verbs, Entities = nouns and their properties).

Comment: Great! Thanks Adrian. 2 questions: where would you store the area of the rectangle, in the entity itself or in a child entity? Now regarding rhe service, I have trouble understanding how to use a service when it is applied to entities.... Many thanks

Comment: You don't need to "store" it. Typically, you don't have to store basic calculations, but rather the raw properties required to generate them.  Having the getter for area is enough, and it can be retrieved on demand from your template.  Printing out rectangle.area will be enough for that.

Services are your verbs; they "do" tasks.  They make create/read/modify, etc. entities.  Your entities should not be aware of them, because entities are data objects only.  One example would be a RectangleRotator: https://gist.github.com/8e852b1c5f11b8000fc3

I'd need a more concrete example to help any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `RectangleDisplay extends rectangleManager` ?
This is the normal way to `extend` a class with what you need, having available all possible properties of the `parent` and possible `override` of it's functions ([here you can read more about it](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)). None of the classes are `final`, so it shouldn't be a problem. Don't forget to take into account classes [`namespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) when you will be working on it.